# Simple sinatra app with sqlite3 works when using WEBrick but not when using apache and passenger

Tags: sqlite, apache2, sinatra, passenger

I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error" message when my app tries to write to my sqlite3 database.

Everything works fine when I'm using WEBbrick, but I get the above error when I'm using Apache and Passenger. My app loads the first page but fails when it tries to POST.

Here is how I have everything setup:

awesome.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'slim'

APP_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{APP_ROOT}/emails.db")

class Email
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :email, String, :required => true
end
DataMapper.finalize

get '/' do
    slim :index
end

post '/add' do
    Email.create params[:email]
    redirect '/'
end
```

config.ru file:

```
require '/var/www/awesome'

root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
set :root, root_dir
set :app_file, File.join(root_dir, 'awesome.rb')
disable :run

run Sinatra::Application
```

httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public
  <Directory /var/www/public>
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Options -MultiViews
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this is at the very bottom of my apache2.conf file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ruby
```

I've also given the group www-data write access to /var/www

--UPDATE--

Here is the output for the "ps axu | grep Pass" command:

```
root     28373  0.0  0.7 220936  1884 ?        Ssl  13:15   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root     28377  0.1  1.0 2067100 2528 ?        Sl   13:15   0:10 PassengerHelperAgent
root     28379  0.0  3.8 111856  9508 ?        Sl   13:15   0:00 Passenger spawn server                                                                                                                                            
nobody   28382  0.0  1.8 169332  4632 ?        Sl   13:15   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
```

I'm running everything as the root user. This is just a test server and I wanted to just get everything working first. I had troubles before with installing ruby system wide so I started over with a clean server and I haven't added any other users.

--UPDATE 2--

emails.db was already set for everyone to read it with chmod 777, but I just changed it to chmod 666. Here is my ls -l output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     www-data   442 Dec 23 13:15 awesome.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     www-data   215 Dec 23 12:41 config.ru
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 12288 Dec 23 12:56 emails.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     www-data    54 Dec 23 10:55 hello.rb
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     www-data  4096 Dec 22 14:50 log
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     www-data  4096 Dec 22 15:34 public
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     www-data  4096 Dec 23 12:03 tmp
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     www-data  4096 Dec 22 17:16 views
```

I then restarted apache with "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart". I know going from chmod 777 to chmod 666 wouldn't fix my problem, but it is probably a little more secure. I re-ran my app and I still get the same "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request." I'm pretty sure it still has something to do with apache and sqlite3 because when I comment out the "Email.create params[:email]" line I don't get the error.

--UPDATE 3--

Here is the output of "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log":

```
96.18.233.137 - - [24/Dec/2012 20:46:54] "GET / " 200 706 0.0274
96.18.233.137 - - [24/Dec/2012 20:46:54] "GET /favicon.ico " 404 18 0.0013
96.18.233.137 - - [24/Dec/2012 20:47:01] "POST /add " 14 - 0.0046
```

And that is all it shows. Chrome shows:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: What is the user who runs Passenger?  You can find using command `ps axu | grep Pass`  So, that user should have write permissions for sqlite database file.  Please show message from apache error log.

Comment: @taro posted above is the output of the ps axu | grep Pass command.

Comment: You can simply grant read/write access to your database to everyone:  `chmod 666 /path/to/emails.db`

Comment: @taro everyone already had read/write access because just before I posted my question here I did chmod 777 emails.db. It still didn't change anything though. I did go ahead and run chmod 666 and you can see the output of my ls -l command above.

Comment: You can find error message in apache error log.

Comment: @taro I posted the output of my apache error log, but it doesn't say much.

Comment: You can create log file in your app's directory: `cd my_app; touch log/dm.log; chmod 666 log/dm.log` and set it in your app:  `DataMapper::Logger.new(File.join(APP_ROOT, 'log/dm.log'), :debug)`

Comment: And you should write your redirect like: `redirect to('/')`